# How to get a php script to print/work

Tags: php

I have:

```
function ListFiles($dir) {

    if($dh = opendir($dir)) {

        $files = Array();
        $inner_files = Array();

        while($file = readdir($dh)) {
            if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file[0] != '.') {
                if(is_dir($dir . "/" . $file)) {
                    $inner_files = ListFiles($dir . "/" . $file);
                    if(is_array($inner_files)) $files = array_merge($files, 

$inner_files); 
                } else {
                    array_push($files, $dir . "/" . $file);
                }
            }
        }

        closedir($dh);
        return $files;
    }
}


foreach (ListFiles

('www.fromtheabsenceofagirlfriendcomesthis.net/sounds/folder1') as $key=>

$file){
    echo $file ."<br />";
}
```

From somewheres on the web, & when I test it (I eventually want to return a random file name into a href - so tips welcome) I get null. & I try opening the php file via the browser, (null), & I tried calling it from a "php" page:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
    src="http://fromtheabsenceofagirlfriendcomesthis.net/sounds/randomfil

    e.php"
    <script>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

But null. What's my problem?

Comment: Are you running the script from the same server as the fromtheabsenceofagirlfriendcomesthis.net domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can't read/list a directory over HTTP. You'll need to use a different protocol to list a directory over the internet: FTP, SSH, etc. You'll need access to the remote server to do this. If the only thing you can use is HTTP, you'll need to retrieve the webpage (= the HTML document) and parse it yourself.

Comment: And if the script is being run from the same server as that fromtheabs... domain, use relative/absolute paths and not a URL.

Comment: hm, maybe i will start a new thread - how do i get a random file (from a directory & subdirectories) & return it to a href? -- new thread?

Comment: Andrew - i tried that first. good to know it HAS TO BE that way, tho.

Comment: i don't know enough to say this is the answer, but it seems like it. sorry to not give you proper Street Cred, but to anyone reading i think this is right. thanks & i guess if you can explain how i WOULD do this, i'd appreciate it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774301/how-do-i-get-a-random-files-url-from-a-directory-subdirectories-return-it

Answer (score 0):

try rewrite www. -> not www, if your want use this at same domain. 
Bua am almost sure that this is bad practice, try using http:// for glob() of directory call's
use directory listing og glob() as ... functions.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load raw html output as a script:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
    src="http://fromtheabsenceofagirlfriendcomesthis.net/sounds/randomfile.php"
<script>
```

This will never work, as your directories+break tags are NOT valid javascript code, so the whole "script" gets nuked because of syntax/parsing errors. If you want to dynamically load directory listings into a script, you'll have to surround the generated directory listing with valid javascript code, and/or fetch the listing from another script via an AJAX call.