# how do i get a random file's url (from a directory & subdirectories) & return it to a id's href?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I tried a php solution but was told in my last question I "can't read/list a directory over HTTP. You'll need to use a different protocol to list a directory over the internet: FTP, SSH, etc. You'll need access to the remote server to do this. If the only thing you can use is HTTP, you'll need to retrieve the webpage (= the HTML document) and parse it yourself." ( [How to get a php script to print/work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774120/how-to-get-a-php-script-to-print-work) )

I would like it to be simple - I can do HTML, I am learning Java, and I am just floundering around with PHP.

**Update:** an example. file.txt, file2.txt, & file3.txt are in /some/directory - I want a PHP script to grab one RANDOMLY & give it to me in a way I can put it in the href of an element. If not PHP, something else? thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what you want. You should reformulate your question if you want useful tips. Give a real example.

Comment: id's don't have hrefs...

Comment: well, lol. i want a randomly chosen file (from a directory & subdirectories)'s URL via php or something, & i want to stick it in the href of an element with an id. i was clear, i thought. i am not using the youthy slang of "random".. haha. *i* thought i was clear. guiman got it i think..

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this.

```
$filenames=glob("files/*.txt");
$count=count($filenames);
if($count>0)
{
    $rndfile=$filenames[rand(0,$count-1)];
    echo '<a href="' . $rndfile . "'>Random file</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need the files:

```
<?php
    [...]
    $files = scandir(dirname(__FILE__));
    $links = array();
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
     links[] = '<a href="http://localhost/url_decoder?file="'.md5_file($filepath.$file).'"> $file';
    }
    <table>
    foreach ($links as $link){ echo "<tr><td>$link</td></tr>";}
    <table>
?>
```

This little script scans the filepath of the current php script and creates one link per file in that directory to another php script that uses the file md5 hashed value as a parameter. Then the decoder should fo the following:

```
<?php
    [...]
    $file_search = $_GET['file'];
    $files = scandir(dirname(__FILE__));//coder and decored located in same folder
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
     if (md5_file(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file) == $file)
     {
      $fd = fopen (dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file, "r")) {
      $fsize = filesize(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file);
      $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
      $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
      switch ($ext) {
        case "pdf":
          header("Content-type: application/pdf");
          header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
       break;
       default;
         header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
         header("Content-Disposition: filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
      }
      header("Content-length: $fsize");
      header("Cache-control: private"); //use this to open files directly
      while(!feof($fd)) {
        $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
        echo $buffer;
      }
      fclose ($fd);
      exit;
     }
    }
?>
```

This is not perfect, and some of the code was taken from this [page](http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-file-download) but at least gives you an idea how to operate. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Man! i am working this out: maybe a little more explanation? i get we're making a list of files.. then what is this decoder - "fo"? - also i don't get "This little script scans the filepath of the current php script and creates one link per file in that directory to another php script..." - it scans it to it? -- basically what should i do with the decoder, how do i use it? ("Drink Your Ovaltine!" - 'better not say that when i run it! lol (re A Christmas Story, the movie))

Comment: any help? appreciate it if so.